# How can I have videos next to each other?

Tags: embedded, video-richmedia

How can I have embed videos next to each other rather than one below the other?

Comment: Create a view and set its style to "boxed" .

Comment: How can I create a view in a webpart zone? I am new to SharePoint. I have three embed videos  on the same webpart, and I want these align next to eachother rather than having one below the that.

Comment: Where these videos are stored?

Comment: I want to embed videos from Lynda.com!